# Is it normal for the pip list in the terminal to be different from the pip list in vscode?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

As you can see in the image, despite the same path, the pip list in the terminal is different from the pip list in the terminal in vscode, is that normal?

When I install mysql-connector-python, I get an error when I install it with vscode my terminal, but it works fine when I install it from the built-in terminal....

I'm just wondering if the two lists are different by default or if it's due to some kind of behavior.

[VSCODE TERMINAL, TERMINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCNdb.jpg)

I thought the same path would result in the same pip list in the built-in terminal and the same pip list in the vscode terminal, but no.

**Edit**

```
[Terminal]
(base) ~ % python --version
Python 3.11.5
(base) ~ % which python
/Users/sehyeon/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) ~ % which pip
/Users/sehyeon/anaconda3/bin/pip

[VScode]
(base) sql_ws % python --version
Python 3.11.5
(base) sql_ws % which python
/Users/sehyeon/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) sql_ws % which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip
```

Comment: type `python --version` in both terminals and `which python` and `which pip`

Comment: [Terminal]
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir ~ % python --version
Python 3.11.5
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir ~ % which python
/Users/sehyeon/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir ~ % which pip
/Users/sehyeon/anaconda3/bin/pip

[VScode]
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir sql_ws % python --version
Python 3.11.5
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir sql_ws % which python
/Users/sehyeon/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir sql_ws % which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip

Comment: you have Python 3.11.5 and 3.12 installed, do you have a virt env active (`base`), if so why is there no `pip` in the virt env, you must inspect the `PATH` env variable for both cases